# seo question: where should my blog sitemap.xml live

Tags: seo, indexing, blogs, sitemap

we have a blog in a sub-directory of the main url.
http://www.domain.com/blog/

the blog is run by wordpress and we are using Google Sitemap Generator to create the XML file.

We have an index of all of our sitemaps in the main sitemap.xml which leads to many sitemaps.

From an SEO standpoint would it be best to link directly to the sitemap that is under the blog directory:
e.g. http://www.domian.com/blog/sitemap.xml

or should be do a cron (daily) to copy the file to the main domain's directory:
e.g. http://www.domain.com/sitemap_blog.xml

which will be linked from the main index with the other sitemaps.

What is the best way from an SEO standpoint???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the sitemap is. you will want to register its location with the search engines you want to be able to find it. The main thing though is to have a link to your sitemap location in the robots.txt file using the following line:

```
Sitemap: <sitemap_location>
```

Your robots.txt file should be in your domain's root.